# Font (Roboto) appears much bolder on Chrome than Firefox (Windows)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm using Roboto font widely through my web app. I'm developing on Linux and everything is fine, but then I checked if it looks the same on Windows, and it doesn't. In Windows-Chrome fonts are much bolder and ugly, also in Opera. Only in Firefox it looks normal (like on every browser in Linux). I have even made a fiddle and compared it on 2 browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/mhk2c4by

```
enter code here
```

[image: Font comparison (Robot 400) Chrome vs. Firefox]

In Chrome on Linux it looks like in Firefox on Windows, as it should.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Most people will be using my app on Windows-Chrome, and I don't like the font one bit. From the picture it doesn't look that bad, but in live app it makes a big difference.

Comment: Try: `body {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;}`

Comment: I tried adjusting -webkit-font-smoothing but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the font in the screenshots is Arial, used as the "sans-serif" fallback. Roboto is not installed by default on Windows (but can be used as a web font, and looks great).

Comment: It was a long time ago, but the fiddle actually has Roboto CSS attached. Look to the left in resources.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in your chrome to enable 2G for web font loading.

```
 chrome://flags/#enable-webfonts-intervention-v2
```

In your code use css reset: [2017’s most popular CSS Reset scripts](http://cssreset.com/)

Or you can create jquery function to detect which browser is used and apply class *.chrome* to body that will change the font to bolder one.

```
function setBrowserClasses() {
    $.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
    if (true === $.browser.chrome) {
        $('body').addClass('chrome');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox probably uses the same text rendering on all systems, while Chrome uses the system one.

Text rendering engines are very complex beasts with different algorithms and defaults from system to system. They won't ever give the same results except on high pixel density screens that make grid-fitting heuristics unnecessary.

One characteristic of the windows stack is that it does not handle unhinted fonts well, make sure you feed it an hinted font.

Otherwise just accept they are different, and that it's fine for their users. Someone that spends its days in windows with windows-style text rendering is not going to complain your app is not Linuxy enough.